# Right angled triangle inscribed in a regular pentagon; find angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

$ABCDE~$ is a regular pentagon. Find $x$.

[image]

I am having a lot of trouble with this geometry problem. Simply using trigonometry seems to always lead me to a dead end and I can't leverage any circle theorems (I chose the midpoint of the long side as the radius as it is a right triangle, but it didn't lead me anywhere). I noticed that the angles of the triangle are akin to dividing the triangle you get when you divide the pentagon into $10$ pieces but I also do not know how to use that information. I tried cutting up the pentagon and gluing it back together, combining with different pentagons. I don't know any more ways of solving geometry problems any more.

Comment: Has any specific been mentioned for the point at which the right angle meets the pentagon's side?

Comment: $\angle ABC=108^\circ$, $\angle ABQ=90^\circ$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If you take ABQ = 90 then the angle near A will be slightly below 45 degrees, not equal to 36. Oops in fact for a given x there may be up to two values of the angle at A, so maybe your suggestion could work

Comment: @MichaelHoppe if P is close to D then PAQ is close to 0

Comment: The only angles specified are the ones shown and the fact that it is a regular pentagon

Comment: @MichaelHoppe how did you know that ABQ is a right angle?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

First of all notice that $\widehat FBD = 36^o$ iff F is on midpoint of EG. This can be seen easily; if F is between midpoint and G then $\angle FAD>36^o$. If F is between midpoint and E the $\angle FAD<36^o$.
We draw a circle center at midpoint of AD.Vertex  B is also on this circle because $\widehat{ABF}=54^o$. Arc FA is $108^o$ because the angle opposite t0 it i.e. $\widehat {ADF}=54^o$. Therefore B must be on the circle. Hence $\widehat{ ABD}=90^o$. Therefore:

$\widehat {FBD}=90-54=36^o$

Finally:

$x=\widehat {DBC}=54-36=18^o$

Now I prove that F must be midpoint of EG.The question is : In pentagon ABCDEG inscribe a right angled triangle such that one angle is $36^o$.

Solution: take an arbitrary point like D on the side EC. Connect A to D. Take midpoint of AD as center and draw a circle which passes vertex B. This circle intersect side EG at point  F. Connect B to F. we have:

$\widehat{ABF}=\widehat{FDA}$

$\widehat {FAD}=\widehat {AFD}-\widehat{FDA}$

Now $\widehat {AFB}=90^o$ because it is opposite the diameter of circle and we want $\widehat{FAD}=36^o$, so we must have $\widehat {FDA}=54^o$. In this case we also must have $widehat {FBA}=54^o$. This is  possible only if FB bisects angle ABC . In a regular pentagon the bisector of the angle on a vertex is perpendicular  on the side opposite  and bisects that side. That is F must be midpoint of EG.

Comment: You simply stated the fact that it is a midpoint without giving a rigorous proof. I can't see it because I'm not measuring the angles. I'm asking for a method of computation. Also, why are you shifting H around instead of F?

Comment: @MarcoLeung I agree with you and as I have mentioned in my answer, it is more based on the insight I got by drawing that I know what it is and it is more an argument than a proof. I started to solve it using coordinate geometry and the angles being $18^0, 36^0, 54^0$ was making it complicated. In fact some angles $\angle KDE$ etc. are in decimals. But interestingly many of the angles are in the form of $x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x$ where $x = 18^0$.

Comment: Your proof is fine, but it is badly written. The first three periods should be omitted altogether, they are only confusing. And the circle mentioned immediately after should be better specified as circle $ADF$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The first thing I would acknowledge that it is a bit of a convoluted proof and is not that straightforward to come to the conclusion without drawing and getting some insights. We know that perpendicular from vertex $C$ to diagonal $BE$ and to side $AE$ will make angle of $36^0 (\angle ICK = 36^0)$ and $\angle BCI = 18^0$. That will also mean $\angle DCI = 90^0$.

Now we are given $\angle DKI = 90^0, \angle KDI = 36^0, \angle DIK = 54^0$. This shows we are talking about the unique construct shown in the diagram.

That means $x = 18^0$.

Now a few interesting facts related to this problem.

We draw perp from two adjacent vertices $C, D$ to the opposite diagonal $BE$ and let the perp lines intersect sides $AE$ and $AB$ at point $H$ and $I$ respectively.

Though it is obvious based on angles but to call out points $H$ and $I$ are not the midpoints of sides $AE$ and $AB$.

Now it is easy to show $\angle EDH = \angle BCI = 18^0$, and CDHI is a rectangle with its center at $J$.

Then we draw the circumscribing circle to this rectangle. It intersects the side $AE$ of the pentagon at point $H$ but also at the midpoint $K$. Similarly points $F$ and $I$ on the side AB. It is $\triangle DKI$ that the question is referring to.